# Boolean. Is string in list and not last position ? Python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make a simple line of code that looks for a certain element in a list and gives a true or false.

I want to know if it's in the list . . . it can be any position in the list BUT if it's the last one, it has to be at another position as well.

examples:

```
my_list = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','def'] #meets criteria
my_list2 = ['abc','ghi','jkl','def'] #does not meet criteria
my_search = 'def'
```

my_list has 'def' in the middle of the list and at the end so that would meet the criteria
my_list2 only has 'def' at the end  so it WOULD NOT meet the criteria

I was trying something along the lines of,

```
(('def' in my_list) and (my_list[-1] == 'def')) or (('def' in my_list) and (my_list[-1] !+ 'def'))
```

but I feel like that is the long way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can just check if it is in the list minus the last element:

```
>> my_list = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','def']
>>> 'def' in my_list[:-1]
True

>>> my_list2 = ['abc','ghi','jkl','def']
>>> 'def' in my_list2[:-1]
False
```

Comment: i don't know why i didn't think of that

Comment: Could have happened to me, really ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sub list...

```
'def' in my_list[:-1]
```

Comment: @mgilson That was impressive... It's only 5 inches from the xterm to the Chromium window!

Answer (score 0):

could you just look at the first n-1 elements?

```
'def' in my_list[:-1]
```

unless I'm misunderstanding that will give you true on the first and false on the second